# How to count dynamic submitting by button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html structure like this

[image]

```
<div class="count-box cocuk-count">
    <span class="count-text">Çocuk:</span>
    <span class="kisi-down"></span>
    <span class="kisi-sayi-text">1</span>
    <span class="kisi-up"></span>
</div>
```

and if I click first button (minus) it must counting forwards or if I click second button (plus) it must counting how can be possible by jquery ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't difficult to at least get a starting point coded and stackoverflow isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For addition

```
$('.kisi-up').click(function(){
   $('.kisi-sayi-text').html(parseInt($('.kisi-sayi-text').html())+1);
});
```

For substraction

```
$('.kisi-down').click(function(){
   $('.kisi-sayi-text').html(parseInt($('.kisi-sayi-text').html())-1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for downvote, can you justify ?

Comment: should always use radix argument

Comment: Is it sufficient enough to down vote my answer  ? It was should, not must to use radix, right ?

Comment: not sure about downvote but not sure why you answered this and didn't vote to close

Comment: IMO, The person (questioner) looks new beginner to me, so it's good to support rather then close or down vote.

Comment: you don't know that and does question meet site guidelines? no

Comment: Not sure about the guidelines but I found to help so I helped

Comment: Hi sorry about discussion I am new on jquery and css and I was trying to do something for myself to understand how to do it

Comment: No problem, Glad to help you but I would recommend to do some Googling before asking any question. Most probably you will find somewhat help from SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        function Counter(counterElement) {
            var counterElementValue = Number(counterElement.text());

            function setCounter(counterValue) {
                counterElement.text(counterValue);
            }

            return {
                add: function () {
                    setCounter(++counterElementValue);
                },
                subtract: function () {
                    setCounter(--counterElementValue);
                }
            }
        };

        var counter1 = new Counter($('.kisi-sayi-text'));

        $('.kisi-down').on('click', function () {
            counter1.subtract();
        })
        $('.kisi-up').on('click', function () {
            counter1.add();
        })
    });
```

You can create severals counters if you want.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Do you think, is it a related answer ?

Comment: I think so, this solves his problem and also can reuse this to create severals counters.

Answer (score 1):

```
var minus = $('.kisi-down:eq(0)'),
plus = $('.kisi-up:eq(0)'),
label = $('.kisi-sayi-text:eq(0)'),
counter = Number(label.html());

function count(isUp) {
    isUp ?counter++:counter--;
    label.html(counter);
};

function up(){
    count(true);
}

function down(){
    if(counter >0) count(false);
}

plus.on('click',up);
minus.on('click',down);
```

Comment: it works very well but it works just one I have three count box and it must work all count box